# Node JS async/await controller issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to use an asynchronous function in my Node API controller, but am receiving an error from my 'error-handler' middleware.

> TypeError: fn is not a function
>       at eval (webpack:///./app/middleware/errorHandler.js?:16:21)

It does not like my 'findAll' function exported from my controller, why is this not a function? Am I exporting the function correctly? Am I using async/await correctly? Do I need a polyfill for this? I understood that async/await was supported from Node v8. I am currently running **Node v11.10** and **Express v4.16.4**.

Here is my routes file:

```
// routes.js
const verifyToken = require('../../middleware/verifyToken.js');
const errorHandler = require('../../middleware/errorHandler.js');

module.exports = app => {
    const controller = require('../../controllers/controller.js');

    app.get(`/collection`, verifyToken, errorHandler(controller.findAll));
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
// controller.js
exports.findAll = async (req, res) => {
    const collections = await collection.find().populate('other');
    res.send(collections);
};
```

Here is my middleware:

```
// errorHandler.js
module.exports = fn => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
  };
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Do I need a polyfill for this?`  No, and I'm wondering why your getting a webpack error.  And errorHandlers are functions not promises.  Also was `VerifyToken` with an upper case a typo..?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `verifyToken.findAll`. There is no variable `findAll` in your routes.js file.

Comment: Apologies, have updated my question to correct the typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is how I would do it if I understand you correctly:

```
// routes.js
const verifyToken = require('../../middleware/verifyToken.js');
const controller = require('../../controllers/controller.js');

module.exports = app => {
  app.get(`/collection`, verifyToken, controller.findAll);
}
```

```
// controller.js
exports.findAll = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const collections = await collection.find().populate('other');
    res.send(collections);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err); // up to you what to do with the error
    next();
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have implemented a try/catch in my controller function but now I receive the following error: `Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

Comment: @Dale Not sure without seeing more code, but it sounds like one of the middlewares you are passing to a route is undefined. Are you still doing `findAll` instead of `controller.findAll` like in your original post?

Comment: no I am not, it appears to be an issue with my controller export. When I console.log controller in my route file i get `undefined`

Comment: Are you doing the `require()` at the top of the file or inside of a function? I've had issues with the latter - I think it's bad practice

Comment: I have tried both, neither work. I agree its bad practice inside of the function, I am compiling my app.js with babel, if I use `export const findAll` instead of `module.exports = {}` this seems to work.

Comment: Why are you using Babel for node? The only reason I'm aware of is for using Typescript. Node8+ supports `async/await` and arrow functions and all that goodness.

Comment: I am rendering my frontend React app server-side so I need to use babel. Thanks for your help, will mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure but is errorHandler expecting fn to be the error? If so, why is it called passing (req, res next)?

I use following structure:

Router

```
// routes.js
const verifyToken = require('../../middleware/verifyToken.js');
const controller = require('../../controllers/controller.js');

var router = express.Router()

router.route('/collection').get(
  verifyToken,
  controller.findAll
)
module.exports = router
```

Controller

```
// controller.js
const asyncUtil = fn =>
  function asyncUtilWrap(req, res, next, ...args) {
    const fnReturn = fn(req, res, next, ...args)
    return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)
  }

module.exports = {
    findAll: asyncUtil(async (req, res, next) => {
        const collections = await collection.find().populate('other'); // you can do try/catch here if you want to handle the error here
        res.send(collections);
};
```

Then Error Handler usually goes at bottom of app.js (but you can place it at bottom of your router):

```
// app.js 
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500)
  res.send(err.message)
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, handling errors this way is cleaner than my approach. But I receive the same error as @Kenmore's solution